# asp button to call java script function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, aspbutton, modal-popup

I am a new developer of asp.net, now I have a problem on the issue of how to call java script function in asp.net. (I am lack of java-script)

I have a java-script code that will show the confirm modal popup like this

```
$('#modals-bootbox-confirm').click(function()
{
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) 
    {
        $.gritter.add({
            title: 'Callback!',
            text: "BootBox Confirm Callback with result: " + result
        });
    });
});
```

I have known that this script binds to item with id "modals-bootbox-confirm" like

```
<input type="button" id="modals-bootbox-confirm" name="Hello"/>
```

but in asp the button will be initial with `type = "submit"` it cannot call this because after click the button it will postback all the time so how to use this script in asp.net

I have tried to change the id in the script to the asp's id but it does not work. How do I get the result from this modal control? Please help.

I know that asp has `onClientClick` but how to apply this script to it?

Answer (score 0):

its easy man,

Just do this

```
<asp:Button Id="aa" runat="server" onClientClick="function1();"/>
```

//and it Javascript turn it into function:

```
<script>

    function1()

    {
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) 
        {
            $.gritter.add({
                title: 'Callback!',
                text: "BootBox Confirm Callback with result: "+ result
            });
        });


    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you. but it can not. But if it is the simple javascript like function script2() {return confirm('Hello!');} it can.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use OnClientClick:

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="doSomething()" runat="server" />
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_button_onclientclick.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Very Short and Simple:**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick='return confirm("Are You Sure?")' />
```